# How to compare Set<String> and String in IoS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, string, type-conversion, set

I am trying to compare Set and String in IoS.But I ended up with exceptions.Can anyone please please tell me how to do it?

```
for product in products{
            if productId==product.productIdentifier
            {
                PurchaseManager.instance.purchaseProduct()
            }
        }
```

Where productId is NSSet type and product.productIdentifier is a String type. I tried to force unwrap.But it did not help me.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `String` and `Set<String>` with `==` , instead you need

```
if productId.contains(product.productIdentifier) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for product in products where productId.contains(product.productIdentifier) {
    PurchaseManager.instance.purchaseProduct()
}
```

`productId` is a set of **unique** strings, so you need to make sure that your `product.productIdentifier` is presented in the set. You cannot compare them as you wrote.

Frankly, the name of the set does not match the logic.